# Calculate mean value of data in R on fixed date range for multiple years

Tags: r, time-series, mean

I have a daily temperature data for more than 40 years. Here is the sample data:

```
       date tmax
1   1971-01-01 18.9
2   1971-01-02 19.0
3   1971-01-03 19.5
4   1971-01-04 19.2
5   1971-01-05 19.5
.
.
.
17536   2020-12-29 19.7
17537   2020-12-30 18.9
```

I want to calculate the mean value of temperature for the growing period of crop ie from 7 June to 9 November for each year. How can we do this in r?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an option -

Get date, month and year from the data, `filter` and keep only the rows from 7 June to 9th November and get average of `tmax` value for each `year`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), 
         day = day(date), 
         month = month(date), 
         year = year(date)) %>%
  filter(between(month, 7, 10) | 
         day >= 7  & month == 6 | 
         day <= 9 & month == 11) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(tmax = mean(tmax, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: How is that substantially differnt from my solution?

Comment: Besides that it is wrong, you want `day` not  `date` in your filter.

Answer (score 1):

### Sample Data

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
d <- tibble(date = seq(as.Date("1971-1-1"), Sys.Date(), by = "day")) %>%
        mutate(tmax = round(rnorm(nrow(d), 20, 3), 1))
```

### A tidyverse solution

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
d %>% 
   mutate(is_crop_season = date %within% interval(ISOdate(year(date), 6, 7), 
                                                  ISOdate(year(date), 11, 9))) %>%
   group_by(is_crop_season, year = year(date)) %>%
   summarise(mean = mean(tmax)) %>%
   pivot_wider(year, 
               is_crop_season, 
               names_glue = "{ifelse(is_crop_season, 'crop_season', 'no_crop_season')}", 
               values_from = mean)
```